Use Equirectangular 360 Photos As Textures for Room Models?

I am in the process of recreating an apartment in Blender and I have some 360 photos of it which I would like to use as textures for the walls, ceiling, and floor of the 3D model.
The apartment's model is made to scale based on measurements I took, but I'm not sure how I can map its UVs to work with my equirectangular photos or if there's a better method for doing this.
If it helps, linked below is a 360 photo and its room model which I would like to apply a texture to in a way that looks similar to this example from the WalkAboutWorlds app.
Test Room With 360 Texture Files
Thank you for any suggestions you have!

I'd say something along the lines of UV Project -> Sphere?

Yes, I agree with @TheLabCat here. Equirectangular projections are 2-dimensional maps of a spherical surface. So to make it look as if your camera was inside the room, you would have to use it on a sphere or the world background. You can try to project pieces of it on the walls of a cube, but this will not be trivial to get to look decently.

Here I show how you can use an equirectangular texture (an HDRI in this case) on either the background or a sphere: How can I use two hdri for sphere and for environment of scene (world). The problem with your reference from WalkAboutWorlds is, this was certainly not made with equirectangular images.

Thank you for your replies! I actually found this tutorial for turning a HDRi into a 3D environment to suit my needs. Also, I looked more into the model from the WalkAboutWorlds App, and surprisingly, it does use equirectangular photos as the textures, but it seems to require a lot more vertices to actually make it work. .
